# What is the correlation between posting GIFs in group chats and IQ

Tags: iq

recently several major Telegram channels I am member of have been heavily ostracizing people posting gifs in such channels, and claiming that it's a sign of retardation. I would not want to jump to such conclusions too fast, so I got curious, maybe there have been any research on this issue?

Comment: Are you sure people are actually intending to make a scientific claim? This sounds like language people use when they *want to discourage a behavior* because *they don't like the behavior*. They don't mean it literally, they mean it as an insult.

Comment: When certain people dislike someone else's behaviors or actions, calling them "retards" is one of several discriminatory epithets applied. Others in include "gay" or "lame" (as in physically disadvantaged). There's no more correlation (or causation) here than there is in people's choice to use "swear words."

Comment: *they* mean it as insult; *I* am looking for a research ..